# How to update email in database using sql update?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my database I have personal email field where Its containing users email. I just want to update all the user email into my test email.

**Personal Email**

ex.

`john@gmail.com` >> `test1@test.com`
`alves@gmail.com` >> `test2@test.com`

Note that I have more than 40,000 records so I want to update personal email field which not equal to null using sql update query

Comment: try this `UPDATE users SET email= CONCAT("test",id,"@test.com")`. id is the AI field

Comment: Sir can you please ellobrate. I am new to this field

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi Missing that part "_email field which not equal to null_"

Comment: @kerbholz I think, there is no need to compare email field

Comment: What is the definition of your table? Meanwhile, be aware that this site is intended for those with some skills in the relevant technology, hence @Ramesh's comment which provides a good solution. AI=auto-increment. If you have no SQL/relational database skills at all, I would suggest you read up a bit before you start - SQL is rather a dangerous tool to use with no skills. There are lots of good introductory textbooks out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess your users table like this:-

```
| id | username  | email            | password   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  john     | john@gmail.com   | $jhbhbjj.. |
| 2  |  alvis    | alvis@gmail.com  | $dcdcdcd.. |
```

Now we are updating every email fields to like below format

```
newemail = "test"+id+"@test.com".
// id is the auto increment column
```

We can join these strings and the column with mysql concat.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

so we are using `concat("test",id,"@test.com")`

After the runing `UPDATE users SET email= CONCAT("test",id,"@test.com")`
 you can get a table like below

```
| id | username  | email            | password   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  john     | test1@test.com   | $jhbhbjj.. |
| 2  |  alvis    | test2@test.com   | $dcdcdcd.. |
```

Comment: I already try it bro I dont have enough reputation to upvote for you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE users
   SET email = CONCAT("test",id,"@test.com")
```

this way you can use the primary key of a table instead of id in an update query.

Comment: UPDATE candidates SET personal_email = CONCAT("test",candidateid,"@test.com") WHERE personal_email != ''

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command ;

```
UPDATE tblEmail SET tblEmail.column = `new value` WHERE tblEmail.column like('old value');
```

The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column. -> https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.